# Calculate a column on select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have two tables, `patients` and `rooms`, and `patients` is

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
    id int,
  room int,
  FOREIGN KEY (room) REFERENCES room (id)
);
```

and `room` is

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    id int,
);
```

I'd like to create a view of `rooms` that includes how many patients are in that room.
I can calculate the number of patients in the room with

```
select count(1) from patients where room = N;
```

for any existing room `N`.
How would I write the `SELECT` statement I need?

---

My best shot at a solution:

```
select *,
       count(1) as patients_in_room
                from patients
                where patients.room = rooms.id
       from rooms;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will bring all the rooms, with `patientsCount = 0` when they are empty.

```
SELECT r.id roomId, coalesce(count(p.room),0) patientsCount
FROM room r left join patients p on r.id = p.room
GROUP BY r.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT room, COUNT(*) patients_in_room
FROM patient
GROUP BY room
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL Aggregate functions, please see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

For what you asked above you can use following query:

```
SELECT room, COUNT(*) FROM patient GROUP BY room
```

Cheers !!